# Issues with designing ground plane for switching relays in high noise environment

Tags: usb, relay, emc, ground-plane, emi-filtering

I am designing a PC Controlled 8 channel Relay using AVR microcontroller.

Here, the relays are on the right side of the board and are controlled by the AVR micro on the left side.

The eight TTL outputs from AVR are connected to a high current darlington pair IC like ULN2003A.

I may use either USB or RS485 interface to connect the board with PC.

Each relay is rated up to 7 A AC switching and there are eight of them. The relays are used to control AC electrical equipment.

PCB is double layered FR4 material.

The green layers in the below image represents the ground plane. The AVR microcontroller section has ground plane on both sides.

[image: Block diagram]

I want the circuit to work reliably in a high noise environment without resetting the AVR micro.

Both Micro and relay drivers are powered by a single 12 V DC adapter. 12 V DC to 12 V relays and 5 V to micro through a linear regulator.

Now my questions are:

- **Should I keep the ULN2003 close to the relays**, so that the length of
  the high current traces going to the relay remains short and make the
  TTL 5V lines to the ULN2003 long or vice versa? Which is better?
- **Do I have to extend the Microcontroller ground plane under the TTL 5 V
  lines going towards ULN2003** as shown in the above image also or
  should I leave them without a ground plane (under the TTL 5 V lines
  only)?
- **Do I have to provide a ground plane under ULN2003A IC and the relay** DC contacts?

Other Suggestions about proper ground designs are welcome.

Comment: Why do you keep using the term *TTL*? Are you actually using TTL logic levels in your design? Or is it just a way to say that you use 5V logic? AVR MCUs are CMOS and their GPIO pins have symmetric drive capabilities (unlike true TTL outputs).

Answer (score 1):

Related reading: 
[Is it right to route AC L/N on different layers on a PCB?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/658777/is-it-right-to-route-ac-l-n-on-different-layers-on-a-pcb/658796#658796) 
[How to make a ground plane for relay PCB switching mains?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/288433/how-to-make-a-ground-plane-for-relay-pcb-switching-mains)

> Should I keep the ULN2003 close to the relays?

Essentially irrelevant.  This is a slow path (~µs rise time), and the relay has good isolation so isn't particularly susceptible to noise.

> Do I have to extend the Microcontroller ground plane under the TTL 5 V lines going towards ULN2003 as shown in the above image also or should I leave them without a ground plane (under the TTL 5 V lines only)?

This would be preferable.  Use one or more vias near the GND pin to tie it to the plane.  Use a supply bypass capacitor nearby as well.

> Do I have to provide a ground plane under ULN2003A IC and the relay DC contacts?

No, not really.  I would probably pour under the coil pins, but it doesn't really mean anything.

You may want snubbers on the contacts, which can otherwise radiate at quite extraordinary levels -- contact arcing is a shockingly (pun intended) nonlinear phenomena, capable of producing nanosecond-scale pulses at high voltage (EFT, Electrical Fast Transients).

An R+C, MOV or TVS across the contacts is typically sufficient for this purpose.  Which choice depends on voltage range and load characteristics.

Answer (score 0):

I once assisted a consultant who had ICs burning out, because his PCB was located only 40 milliMeters from a 5,000 volt power buss that switched 2,000 amps in 1 microsecond.

The upset in the Ground plane was computed, assuming 4" by 4" loops in the Ground, as

V = [MU0*MUr*Area/(2*pi*Distance)] * dI/dT

which simplifies to

Vinduce = 2e-7 * Area/Distance * dI/dT

and inserting numbers, we have

Vinduce = [2e-7 * 0.1meter*0.1meter / 0.04 meters] * 2e+9 amp/sec

Vinduce (that is, voltage induced into loops in the Ground plane)
= (2e-7 * 1/4) * 2e+9

Vinduce (from this  10MegaWatt bus) is

100 volts

So you need to identify your rate-of-change of currents, and compute how much GROUND UPSET can be generated.

Oh.....how much credibility does this math have? 100 volts around 4"by4" loop. I had the "consultant" make a 1"by1" loop, attached to coax cable; note this is 1/16 of the area I used in the math, so we could expect 100/16 = 7 volts.

What did the consultant measure? 3 volts, or 4 volts in some locations on the PCB. Versus 7 volts predicted. For a 2,000 amp flat buss (air cooled, I recall) located 4cm away.