# Is it right to route AC L/N on different layers on a PCB?

Tags: pcb, ac, routing

I'm working on a PCB for a trailing-edge dimmer. Is it OK to route the AC live and neutral in opposite layers?

In the image, you can't see the AC neutral (blue), behind the AC_L, but it is there.

This is for a 110 VAC, 1 A per channel. The AC bar in the bottom is 2.5 mm thick (1 oz). I made this bar without the mask, so I can add some solder to increase thickness. I don't know if it is needed though.

[image]

This is what it looks like:

[image]

If anyone is interested: the project is on [GitHub](https://github.com/0x3333/ACTrailingDimmer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FYI, some comments regarding the overall design:

- D10/D11 (and similar) aren't needed; the body diode is rated more current than 1N4007, and at lower voltage drop.
- MOSFETs aren't rated for fusing current, so it's not obvious that the fuse will open before they fail.  (In particular, they will come out of saturation by 30A or so, and fail in under 100µs at that condition; meanwhile, under fault conditions, the fuse can let through over 1kA before opening in a few ms.)

  Remember the fuse is only to protect the wiring; if anything else survives, it's only a bonus.

  Rectifier diodes, or a thyristor type switch, can survive these conditions; and are typically rated with a fusing I<sup>2</sup>t so can be designed to survive the let-through of a given fuse.  If you wish to have this level of robustness, consider a thyristor (TRIAC) type SSR (which will displace the trailing-edge aspect, of course).
- MOV to protect semiconductors is dubious, in general; be careful.  In this case, the choice of a 130VAC MOV gives clamping voltage under 700V (MOSFET rating) up to 1kA surge; which is unlikely to be seen by the switch into a typical load.  This is acceptable.  Notice it will not function on 240V mains, and higher rated MOV, and likely MOSFETs, are required.

Regarding the layout:

- Good overall, at a glance!  The remaining points are fairly minor.
- I wouldn't expose traces for thickening them.  Better to just splurge for 2oz copper instead: it's standard proto service at most fabs, and costs little extra.
- PCB traces must not break before the fuse does.  Fusing ratings aren't easy to find, and I'm not sure that there's a general standard regarding it.  Generally speaking, traces designed for low temperature rise (say 10°C at rated current) will handle it fine.

  (When inspecting a design for approval, UL (and etc.) will test mains-connected traces for 5× overload or thereabouts, and make recommendations as needed.  Trace ampacity depends widely on trace length, heatsinking (connected wide areas / pours, as well as inner copper planes) and spacing, so it's probably easier/more certain to just test everything.)
- The ground plane section can be improved some.  Pour doesn't need to extend around the isolator pads, improving creepage (this is a minor difference, with the slot there already); the output traces can be grouped tighter under the MCU, staying under the pour (mind the inside corner), and the pin-5 trace can be routed on the bottom.
- Several top-side traces can be routed on the bottom to avoid cutting up the plane.  The SMT jumpers could be placed closer to J4, avoiding the trace crossing to J4 pins 3/4.  ZC and +5V as well.  Don't be afraid to use more vias: they're practically free.
- The above steps will improve ground continuity, preserving its solidity as a plane.  Grounding can be improved further by pouring both layers and adding stitching vias, so that any given stretch of trace is surrounded by a loop closed between top/bottom layers, within say a couple inches.  This hardly seems worth it for such a simple board, but can be important on more complicated designs.
- Check the PSU datasheet if you should have more bypass/filtering on board (input or output).  Typically, SMPS modules are a bit dirty, or skimp on these for space and cost reasons.  A full EMI evaluation would be necessary to know for sure how much EMI filtering might be needed, but it would be safe enough to toss in a common-mode choke at its AC input and some Y-type capacitors between AC_N, and GND and/or chassis GND (if available on screws).
- Speaking of screws, consider removing copper ring/plating on the one in the middle.  Or maybe many of them, if you're not making an electrical connection to them.  This improves isolation to AC_N/L at the middle-bottom of the board for example.

A somewhat higher priority note about I2C: it's not good off-board.  I suppose for a display, you might not have much choice, but do keep lead lengths to an absolute minimum, and add filtering (and perhaps ESD protection) on both ends of the link if possible.  (Very little filtering is possible without greatly compromising bitrate; again, it's not good off-board.)  If any length at all is required, use a shielded cable, and preferably use connectors with alternating ground and signal lines (VCC counts as ground for RF purposes).  These requirements are relaxed if the project resides inside a metal enclosure, but beware that the display is exposed (you've got to be able to see it..!) so can be struck by ESD either directly, or from nearby conductive objects inducing ESD onto it.  An insulating coverlay helps (and in extreme cases, a conductive (fine mesh, metallization, or ITO coated glass) cover can be used, but that's probably overkill here!).

Good luck!

Comment: OMG, absolute legend. I'll read it carefully again and get back with some comments. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Regarding the Diodes, absolutely spot on, datasheet is clear about that. Fuses removed, the breaker is OK to handle any fault. The idea of the MOV is to protected the load, but I can add a single MOV in the input of the system and it will protected the loads and the dimmer for any surge in the supply, right?

Comment: 2oz it is going to be. No approval, so not diving deep into this. Ground plane fixed. The pin 5 trace crosses the pin 6, only if I added a via or go around pin 6.

Regarding the SMD jumpers, I found an issue, it must have a closed jumper in the ZC pin, so I can break and jump to the other jumpers. The OLED is optional, they use the same pins that can be used by the ZC(Don't know yet), that's why they are connected. The i2c used by the OLED will be connected directly to the connector in the display, no cables, not sure if it will be used though.

Comment: If I add ground pours in both layers, is that OK to cut the pour, right? I mean, if I have pours in both layers, I can just route in the shortest way, and I'm done?

Will add some bypass capacitor to the PSU.

Comment: I wouldn't remove the fuses necessarily, just note the behavior. Note also that a common fuse at the inlet has to be rated for the total, and then every branch circuit has to be rated the same (total), since they won't be individually fused at less. If the pour is stitched around the cuts, that's fine.

Comment: Updated project in github based on your feedback. Thanks for that!

Comment: You can (and probably should) extend ground pour around the signal traces to the optos; the point was just not to wrap around the component pads where it reduces isolation distance. You have no stitching, so the grounding is very poor, particularly where the traces overlap (between pins 4/5, and 6 and 7). Consider the negative space around traces, and stitch it like so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuxdk.png (but unlike this, disable thermal relief for vias). Isolation slot can be smaller too, you have adequate clearance under PS1 and the long span above ~D2.

Comment: Stitching doesn't need to be obsessively around each trace, grouping them into buses is fine.

Comment: Just for the ones in the future, there are two nice videos about the routing, vias and return path: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=icRzEZF3eZo and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=52fxuRGifLU

Answer (score 2):

If your question is about the voltage isolation between the two traces, the answer is yes, the PCB material is a better insulator than the surface of the PCB, which would be the case if the traces were on the same layer.

I have not looked at current capability of the traces. In any line connected device, you should have a fuse somewhere that blows instead of burning up PCB traces, if something should fail.